# Scraping the scores (Location, Cleanliness etc.) from Airbnb

Tags: python, json, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the Location Score, Cleaningness Score etc. from the airbnb listings.

My problem is that when I am trying to scrape them from one page I scrape them normally with multiple ways.

But when I add this code in my loop to scrape them from multiple page either I get an error or I get back an empty column/list.

Let me show you what I mean.

This is my imports:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time
import re
import requests
from datetime import date


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.maximize_window()
```

Some ways that I can get what Scores:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,20)
test_url = 'https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/51833563?adults=1&children=0&infants=0&check_in=2022-09-18&check_out=2022-09-23&federated_search_id=96d13170-4935-492e-ad71-ffe0c39bc006&source_impression_id=p3_1663079036_%2FKJDqmaFlIk3h8a6'
driver.get(test_url)
time.sleep(3)
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
scores = []
Cleanliness=  driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//span[@class='_4oybiu'][1]")[0].text
Accuracy= driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//span[@class='_4oybiu'][1]")[1].text
Communication=  driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//span[@class='_4oybiu'][1]")[2].text
Location= driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//span[@class='_4oybiu'][1]")[3].text
Check_in= driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//span[@class='_4oybiu'][1]")[4].text
Value= driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//span[@class='_4oybiu'][1]")[5].text
```

When I add this in my loop I get an error that the list is out of index.

This is another way to scrape the information that i want:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,20)
test_url = 'https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/51833563?adults=1&children=0&infants=0&check_in=2022-09-18&check_out=2022-09-23&federated_search_id=96d13170-4935-492e-ad71-ffe0c39bc006&source_impression_id=p3_1663079036_%2FKJDqmaFlIk3h8a6'
driver.get(test_url)
time.sleep(3)
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
scores = []
Cleanliness=  driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"_4oybiu")
for i in Cleanliness:
    scores.append(i.text)
```

When i add this in my loop I get back an empty list.

And this is the code inside the loop:

```
url = 'https://www.airbnb.com/s/Thessaloniki--Greece/homes?tab_id=home_tab&flexible_trip_lengths%5B%5D=one_week&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&place_id=ChIJ7eAoFPQ4qBQRqXTVuBXnugk&query=Thessaloniki%2C%20Greece&date_picker_type=calendar&search_type=user_map_move&price_filter_input_type=0&ne_lat=40.66256734970964&ne_lng=23.003752862853986&sw_lat=40.59051931897441&sw_lng=22.892087137145978&zoom=13&search_by_map=true&federated_search_session_id=1ed21e1c-0c5e-4529-ab84-267361eac02b&pagination_search=true&items_offset={offset}&section_offset=2'

p_lat = re.compile(r'"lat":([-0-9.]+),')
p_lng = re.compile(r'"lng":([-0-9.]+),')

data = []
calendar = []





for offset in range(0, 20, 20):
    print('offset:', offset)
    
    driver.get(url.format(offset=offset))
    time.sleep(2)
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

    detailed_pages = []
    
    for card in soup.select('div[class="c4mnd7m dir dir-ltr"] a[class="ln2bl2p dir dir-ltr"]'):
        link = 'https://www.airbnb.com' + card['href']
        detailed_pages.append(link)
        
    print('len(detailed_pages):', len(detailed_pages))
    
    for number, page in enumerate(detailed_pages, 1):
        print(number, 'page:', page)

        driver.get(page)
        time.sleep(5)
        
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
        Cleanliness=  driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//span[@class='_4oybiu'][1]")[0].text
        Accuracy= driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//span[@class='_4oybiu'][1]")[1].text
        Communication=  driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//span[@class='_4oybiu'][1]")[2].text
        Location= driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//span[@class='_4oybiu'][1]")[3].text
        Check_in= driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//span[@class='_4oybiu'][1]")[4].text
        Value= driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//span[@class='_4oybiu'][1]")[5].tex
```

Answer (score 0):

To investigate the element, I found the element you are after is inside `scripts` tag. You need the get the text from script tag and then covert into `json` object and then traverse the tree to get the ratings.

```
driver.get('https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/51833563?adults=1&children=0&infants=0&check_in=2022-09-18&check_out=2022-09-23&federated_search_id=96d13170-4935-492e-ad71-ffe0c39bc006&source_impression_id=p3_1663079036_%2FKJDqmaFlIk3h8a6')
element=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "script#data-deferred-state")
elementHtml=element.get_attribute("innerHTML")
json_object = json.loads(elementHtml) # convert string to json object
parent=json_object['niobeMinimalClientData'][0]
child=parent[1]
eventlogging=child['data']['presentation']['stayProductDetailPage']['sections']['metadata']['loggingContext']['eventDataLogging']

print("Accuracy Ratings : " + str(eventlogging['accuracyRating']))
print("Cleanliness Ratings : " + str(eventlogging['cleanlinessRating']))
print("Communication Ratings : " +str(eventlogging['communicationRating']))
print("Location Ratings : " +str(eventlogging['locationRating']))
print("Checking Ratings : " +str(eventlogging['checkinRating']))
```

You need to import below library

```
import json
```

**Output:**

```
Accuracy Ratings : 5
Cleanliness Ratings : 4.9
Communication Ratings : 5
Location Ratings : 4.8
Checking Ratings : 5
```